# hibernate persistence

Tags: hibernate

I work with hibernate I create `hibernate.cgf.xml` and the mapping file.
I create a class java for the entity and the `hibernateUtil.java` and when i run the test main it generate this:

```
Exception in thread "main" net.sf.hibernate.MappingException: No persister for: fr.hibernate.projet.model.Employe
    at net.sf.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.getPersister(SessionFactoryImpl.java:347)
    at net.sf.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.getClassPersister(SessionImpl.java:2690)
    at net.sf.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.getPersister(SessionImpl.java:2697)
    at net.sf.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.saveWithGeneratedIdentifier(SessionImpl.java:763)
    at net.sf.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:738)
    at fr.hibernate.projet.test.Test.main(Test.java:32)
```

The database is still empty.

Comment: showing the hibernate configuration file might help us to help you

Answer (score 1):

"no persiter" usually means that there is no mapping definition for the given type. Did you load the mapping definitions in your program?

**EDIT**: You may have an issue with the configuration file. It must be on a path where it can be found. [Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=hibernate.properties%20not%20found).

Comment: 2 mai 2011 09:09:26 net.sf.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>

INFO: hibernate.properties not found


INFO: Mapping resource: fr.hibernate.projet.model.Employe.hbm
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
 at fr.hibernate.projet.test.Test.main(Test.java:16)